# Create and sort 2d array from file

Tags: java, arrays, file, sorting, multidimensional-array

Okay so basically I have to accomplish 2 things with this code. 1. Sort the two columns from the file into an array and 2. arrange them in order from largest to smallest based on the second column.

Before I can begin the sorting algorithm I need to get the array to sort properly. Any help would be great. Thanks. 
I have listed a hyperlink the the contents of the file below.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
public class sorter{
    public static int id = 0;
    public static int score = 0;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner inFile = null;
        int ROWS = 21;
        int COLS = 2;
        try {
            inFile = new Scanner (new File ("sorter.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
            System.exit(0); 
        } 
        while (inFile.hasNextLine()){
            String str = inFile.nextLine();
            String [] parts = str.split(" ");
            String part1 = parts[0];
            String part2 = parts[1];
            id = Integer.parseInt(part1);
            score = Integer.parseInt(part2);
            int[ ][ ] array1 = new int[id][score];
            for (int i =0; i < ROWS; i++) { 
                for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) { 
                    System.out.print(" " + array1[21][2]); 
                } 
                System.out.println(""); 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

[Link to file contents](http://bit.ly/1nIx1d9)

Comment: Do you mean sorting the two columns first by the value of the first column and use the value of the second column to break ties?

Comment: No. Basically the second column is like a test score and the first column is like the students id. The score column needs to be sorted largest to smallest and the id needs to stay with the appropriate score.

Comment: Do you need to implement your own sorting algorithm, or it's fine to use the Java's sorting utilities?

Comment: Either way, I imagine it'd be easier to use a built in sorter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Map (preferably a Treemap) where the keys are column 1 (student ID) and values are column 2 (the test score). Then you can sort it by value. The sorting-by-value needs to be careful, because the usual way of doing it will not work if two students have the same test score. One way of doing this is as follows:

```
<K,V extends Comparable<? super V>> SortedSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> entriesSortedByValues(Map<K,V> map, final int order) {
    SortedSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> sortedEntries = new TreeSet<>(
        new Comparator<Map.Entry<K,V>>() {
            public int compare(Map.Entry<K,V> e1, Map.Entry<K,V> e2) {
                return (order > 0) ? compareToRetainDuplicates(e1.getValue(), e2.getValue()) : compareToRetainDuplicates(e2.getValue(), e1.getValue());
            }
        }
    );
    sortedEntries.addAll(map.entrySet());
    return sortedEntries;
}
```

where

```
private static <V extends Comparable<? super V>> int compareToRetainDuplicates(V v1, V v2) {
    return (v1.compareTo(v2) == -1) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create a class to hold the data of each pair  and implements the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface to define the order criterion, then you can use the `Arrays.sort()` method. Here is a possible solution:

```
public void solve()
{
    try {
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("input.dat"));
        int ROWS = 21;
        int COLS = 2;
        Score[] scores = new Score[ROWS];
        int i = 0;
        while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = inFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            int id = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            int score = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
            scores[i] = new Score(id, score);
            i++;
        }

        Arrays.sort(scores);
        for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
            System.out.println(scores[i].getId() + "-> " + scores[i].getScore());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {

    }
}

class Score implements Comparable<Score> {
    private int id;
    private int score;

    Score(int i, int s)
    {
        id = i;
        score = s;
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public int getScore() { return score; }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Score other)
    {
        if (getScore() > other.getScore())
            return -1;
        else if (getScore() < other.getScore())
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

}
```